# Excluding one file in NSIS file copying command (recursively)

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to run this from a script.
What I'm trying to do here is copy all files in package directory to the current outpath, excluding only `wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar`. this won't fail the script compilation but won't exclude the file either, any ideas ?

```
File /r /x "package\lib\wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar" "package\*.*"
```

thanks,
Ohad

Answer (score 3):

Well, it still strikes my as odd, but this is the solution

```
File /r /x wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar package\*.*
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that worked for me.  I needed to exclude a folder also...the .svn folder.

> ;--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>   
>    ;-- Add MVC Web Files
>   
>    ;--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> SetOverwrite on
>   
>    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\WebServer\"
>   
>    File "C:\mvcwebsite\favicon.ico"
>   
>   
>    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\WebServer\Content"
>   
>    **File /r /x '.svn' 'C:\mvcwebsite\Content*.*'***
>   
>   
>    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\WebServer\Scripts"
>   
>    **File /r /x '.svn' 'C:\mvcwebsite\Scripts*.'**
>   
>   
>    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\WebServer\Views"
>   
>    **File /r /x '.svn' 'C:\mvcwebsite\Views*.*'**
>   
>   
>    ;--//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is the 'File' [NSIS Help](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.5)

Answer (score 1):

/x is picky about the format of the string, some of the nsis switches prefer the switch itself to be part of the string, eg "/x foo bar" but I'm not sure if that helps in this case...